# ROWNUM and DISTINCT in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, rownum

I am facing trouble trying to code the following query:

```
SELECT id,
       contractnumber,
       partyid,
       entity,
       product,
       fecha
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT (contractdet.id),
         contractdet.contractnumber,
         contractdet.partyid,
         contractdet.entity,
         contractdet.product,
         contractdet.fecha,
         ROWNUM AS rnumber
  FROM contractdet
    INNER JOIN contractcust ON contractcust.contractdet_id = contractdet.id
    INNER JOIN customerdet ON customerdet.partyid = contractdet.partyid
  WHERE TO_CHAR(contractdet.fecha, 'YYYYMM') <= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(20160828, 'YYYYMMDD'), -3), 'YYYYMM')
    AND contractdet.product = 'TC'
  ORDER BY contractdet.id ASC
)
WHERE rnumber BETWEEN ?   AND ?
ORDER BY id
```

I use it in in a piece of java code in order to page the process, repeating the query and retrieving 1000 results each time. The main problem I have is that the DISTINCT order only applies to the interval I am in, and not to the whole set of results, so it retrieves duplicated rows when I mix the output of all the queries I have done.

Comment: Make some effort to format your query.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is ***NOT*** a function. It always applies to **all** columns in your query.

Comment: Also: `TO_DATE(20160828, ..)` is wrong. `to_date()` expects a string (`varchar`) not a number and you do not need `to_date()` at all there. The expression can also be simplified to `ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2016-08-28', -3)`

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. I mean I want DISTINCT to apply to all the rows in the database, but retrieve 1000 results, each time I submit the query. Currently, as it is, it happens to me that there could be a row with the same ID comparing the outputs the first time I submit the query and the second, for instance.

Comment: @pedrero . . . Why do you say:  `DISTINCT (contractdet.id)`?  The parentheses mean *nothing*.  As a_horse_with_no_name says, the `distinct` applies to all columns.

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean please? I ask because as things stand, your query is processed in its entirety (including the distinct) *before* selecting the rows you're interested in. I wonder if what you're seeing is actually a case of some more rows got inserted in between you fetching the first set of rows and the next set. I suggest you either change your code to run the ordered query once and then fetch X number of rows at a time as and when you need it, or set the transaction isolation level as serializable for the duration of the time you need to read from that cursor.

Comment: (The serializable transaction isolation level means that even if people update/delete/insert rows, your session won't see those changes, so when you run the select statement multiple times, it'll be running against the same data each time. Bear in mind that if you run in this state long enough, you could end up getting snapshot too old errors, when the UNDO tablespace has had to overwrite data that your session may still be relying on. Also, the longer you leave it, the more inaccurate the results are likely to get.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to select all the rows, avoiding duplicated Ids. If DISTINCT applies to all columns, what do you suggest me to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a CTE in your SQL in Java?

Here is an example:

```
with distinctRecords as (
    select distinct myCol, rownum rnum
    from myTable
    order by myCol
)
select *
from distinctRecords
where rnum between ? and ?;
```

Comment: That is, in effect, what the OP is doing when they use the inline-view. It's still a subquery (and one that can't be unnested, due to the presence of the rownum) regardless of whether you declare the subquery in the with clause or in the from clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
with t as (
      <your subquery here without the `distinct`>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will choose one arbitrary row per `id`.  You can control which row is selected (say the oldest or the newest) by changing the `order by` in the subquery.